# Finding out the dimensions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A square  room having a total floor area  $1000000 m^2$ is to be partitioned into two rooms  by a single interior wall. The difference between the perimeters of the resulting tow offices is to be 400 feet. What are the dimensions (length and breadth) in feet of the two rooms I am having a little bit difficulties to understand this math

I can not  write down the reasoning because, I didn't understand the question. Can you help me  ? I'm confused because  what they meant by **single interior wall**?  How will I  write an equation of the length and breadth?

Comment: Are the units really supposed to be m$^2$ and feet?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the wall will be placed straightly somewhere along the office.

Suppose the office has side of square $a$. Depending on the position where you place the wall:  you obtain two offices of dimensions $x,a$ and $a-x,a$.
In this case find $x$ based on the conditions given:

$\begin{cases}a^2=1000000 \\2(a-x+a)- 2(x+a)=400 \end{cases}$

Comment: aren't a and b   same due to the square  office?

Comment: Oh yes. My bad.